# Android:Call Observer in a for loop and returning values

Tags: android, asynchronous, rx-java, rx-android

I am very new to asynchronous programming.I am reading all the data of database in Json array and then iterating it in the observer from where I call another observer to post data to server.But the problem is I only receives first value of json array and then it terminates. Is there any thing present in Rx java to handle this thing?.I want to send value to server one by one from json array. Should I use flatmapiterable to return data to serverpost observer? or should I use some another technique?

Here is my code:

```
return getdatafromDb().flatMap(new Func1<String, Observable<String>>() {
            public Observable<String> call(String data) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONObject(data).getJSONArray("sql_data");
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                        datamaker.money = (Double) jsonarray.getJSONObject(i).get("money");
                        datamaker.income = (Double) jsonarray.getJSONObject(i).get("income");
                        datamaker.tag = (String) jsonarray.getJSONObject(i).get("tag");
                        return serverpost(datamaker); //this calls another observer to post data to server
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                 return  nothing;

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies as this is in Java 8:

```
return getdatafromDb()
   .flatMapIterable(data -> new JSONObject(data).getJSONArray("sql_data")) 
   .cast(JSONObject.class) 
   .map(o -> {
       DataMaker datamaker = new DataMaker(); // whatever, but use new instance
       datamaker.money = (Double) o.get("money");
       datamaker.income = (Double) o.get("income");
       datamaker.tag = (String) o.get("tag");
       return datamaker;
   })
   .flatMap(datamaker -> serverpost(datamaker));
```

Some suggestions:

- instead of parsing the JSON objects manually all the time, make the getDataFromDB return an actual honest-to-god parsed object.
- extract the datamaker stuff into a method, or if it's used enough times, as a static method on datamaker.
- if the type that `getJsonArray` returns isn't Iterable, make it so.

Comment: No problem Thank you. Is it possible for you to make it without lambda expressions?